# Get value of next text after search string in website via xpath in google-sheets

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I'm using Google Sheet **IMPORTHTML()** to get the text from a website. I am trying to get the **text after a certain search string** via IMPORTHTML() in Google Sheet using XPath.

As an example, I would like to extract number of rooms and living space from the websites below
https://www.comparis.ch/immobilien/details/favorite?id=26720381

https://www.comparis.ch/immobilien/details/favorite?id=26714976

when i extract the xpath via chrome, it unfortunately isn't always exactly the same for each url. That's why I wanted to try with searching a string:

```
//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p
//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/p/span
```

Plan is therefore to have in column A a list of urls, in row 1 the respective xpath (incl. search string like "room" or "living space" and a table where =importxml($A2,B$1) would use these urls and xpaths to search for the respective values.

I was trying to get the following-sibling after the place where it found for example the string "room" or "living space"

Help is much appreciated as I am new and lost at the moment. Best, Ueli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about modifying your xpath as follows?

#### Modified xpath:

```
//p[@class='css-1ush3w6 excbu0j2' and ../..//span[text()='Zimmer']]
```

#### Result:

When this modified xpath is used for your 2 URLs, the following result is obtained.

[image]

In this sample, the URL and `=IMPORTXML(A1, "//p[@class='css-1ush3w6 excbu0j2' and ../..//span[text()='Zimmer']]")` is put to the cells "A1" and "B1", respectively.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: Perfect. This one works like a charm and I managed to get several fields easily!

Comment: @Ueli Nobs Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP("Zimmer", IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='css-1wfw5hl excbu0j4']"), 2, 0)
```

and drag down:

[image]